# How to make a function pointer constant

Tags: c++, function-pointers

A typical getter/setter looks like this:

```
void setName(const std::string& _name) { name = _name; }
std::string getName() const { return name; }
```

How can I do the same if the member is a function pointer like this:

```
void setBotFunc(int(*botFunc)()) { botFunction = botFunc; }
int (*getBotFunc() const)() { return botFunction; }
```

Particularly I don't know how to declare the setter in a way that says 'I will only read and not modify the pointer (value)'. Does this even make sense? `const int (*botFunct)()` is obviously treated like a function which returns a `const int`.

Comment: The pointer value is copied either way... I don't see much point in making the pointer variable const.

Comment: Use a typedef for function types, then you won't even see a problem anymore.

Comment: @StoryTeller When the function pointer param is defined as `const`, any accidental attempts to modify it within the `setBotFunc()` will result in an `error: assignment of read-only parameter` during compilation. This is better than the alternative which is a seg-fault during run-time later, while trying to jump to the address pointed by the accidentally modified function pointer param.

Comment: @TheCodeArtist, I dare say that in the case of a typical getter/setter the OP asks about, that's unlikely to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void setBotFunc( int(* const botFunc)() )
{
    botFunction = botFunc;
}
```